# What's main difference between Docker and Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, virtualization

Could we use to host Java and PHP runtime (2 application) on the same server using Docker or Kubernates.

Comment: Yes you can. Kubernetes schedules docker containers. So you can use kubernetes to deploy your two applications eg. at the same node (as one pod), or at different node (multiple pods). and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what you're asking doesn't quite make sense.

Kubernetes is a production management and orchestration system for Docker containers.